# Android ArCore glb model

Tags: android, 3d, rendering, arcore

I'm having some problems with ArCore and rendering some .glb models.

What I do is convert .obj's online to .glb files. 
Some of the obj have textures attached to them and some don't.
If I render a .glb in ARCore that was converted with textures everything looks good. Shadows are good out of the box and all that.

But if I do it with a glb that was converted without textures the 3d model is just grey without shadows. The model has depth and all that but it feels like there is no light hitting it.

I need to be able to load models dynamically, so using google SceneForm is not possible.

Any tips forward would help!!

Answer (score 0):

check this post

[How to prepare a 3D model to embed in an AR App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602123/how-to-prepare-a-3d-model-to-embed-in-an-ar-app/58605276#58605276)

you can certainly add dynamic texture in android ar core